# How do i get the order ID and Order Subtotal in the credit memo page?

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer

Im currently trying to write a piece of code that refunds an order and attach it to the "refund" button in the credit memo page using the "sales_order_payment_refund" event.

But, right now, I want to be able to get ***Order_ID*** and ***Order_Subtotal*** from the credit memo page of the order I have opened to proceed, how can I retrieve those 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by placing this code in your constructor to make an object of the creditmemo collection

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Collection $creditmemoCollection,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->creditmemoCollection = $creditmemoCollection;
    ...
}
```

and then inside your function, use the credit memo collection to retrieve the Order_ID and Order_Subtotal like so:

```
$this->creditmemoCollection->getSubtotal();
$this->creditmemoCollection->getRealOrderId();
```

Comment: got error
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Sales\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Order\\Creditmemo\\Collection::getRealOrderId()

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoRepository $сreditmemo, 
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->сreditmemo = $сreditmemo;
    ...
}
.............
$orderId = $this->сreditmemo->get(
    $this->getRequest()->getParam('creditmemo_id')
)->getOrderId();
```